# What is Johnny Cage's green armor?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

***MORTAL KOMBAT X STORY SPOILERS BELOW***

---

In Mortal Kombat X's story, Johnny Cage gains his patented green armor when Sonya was in trouble.

[image]

Later in the game, and again, **spoilers to the story**, his daughter Cassie gets his green armor when Johnny is in trouble. She even mentions that it runs in the family.

[image]

I always thought that this power was something that Johnny learned, not something that he was born with. Cassie did not go through the same martial arts training that her father did. MKX also doesn't explain what this power is.

So, what is it and why does Cassie have this ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although Johnny Cage is a human being, he possesses superhuman powers. According to MK 2011, Johnny descended from a Mediterranean cult that bred warriors for the gods: warriors with special abilities. One of these is the ability to propel himself forward and increase the strength of his blows. **When Cage uses this power, afterimages of a green color are produced**. Cage can augment the power of these shadow attacks, which are represented by afterimages of a red color. In addition to these physical shadow abilities, Cage also has the ability to launch blasts of energy.
>
> As shown in Mortal Kombat X, **Johnny Cage can also harness this energy and encase his body with it**, strong enough to withstand a death blow from Shinnok without receiving any injury to his person.

[From the Mortal Kombat wikia page about Johnny Cage](http://mortalkombat.wikia.com/wiki/Johnny_Cage)